# Can't view deleted content through my phone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges

I can't see deleted posts through my phone, even though I have the rep, and I can see deleted qiestions on a computer.

Using the android app.

Comment: Assuming this is in the android app: can you see it on the mobile web site?

Comment: I didn't try on the mobile website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Our applications use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) which currently does not have any access to deleted material.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing with the iOS app:

[image]

This [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/22345/20749) has a lot of deleted answers, yet only one shows.

It isn't necessarily a bug, maybe it was made on purpose to not show deleted answers on mobile apps.

You can still see deleted answers from your mobile web browser (mobile version of skeptics.se):

[image: nn]